# При записи в csv (python) строки чередуются через одну пустую строку

Tags: python, csv, python-faq

Всем доброго времени суток.
С Питоном начал знакомиться пару часов назад. (потому что нужно было написать парсер)
Собственно проблему вы скорее всего прочитали уже в заголовке поста.
При вот таком коде:

```
import csv
with open('1.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow( ('sdfsdf', 'sdfdsfsd', 'sdfsdfsd', 'sdfsdfsd', '1223423424') )
    w.writerow( ('sdfsdf', 'sdfdsfsd', 'sdfsdfsd', 'sdfsdfsd', '1223423424') )
```

Я получаю вот такой выхлоп:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте 1.csv текстовым едитором и опубликуйте его содержимое как текст вместо картинки.

Comment: Добрый день. 
Спасибо за отзыв на вопрос, проблему я уже решил, и только зря тревожил Вас.

Comment: Вы нисколько меня не по тревожили, наоборот,  счёл бы за честь хоть чем бы быть полезным Вам. Успешного дня и остатка рабочей недели.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы не было лишних пустых строк (пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)), поменяйте на:

```
with open('1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, доки тоже читал, но на данную манипуляцию консоль отвечает:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Впрочем, с проблемой я уже разобрался.
Для функции writer(), нужно было добавить параметр lineterminator='\n'

Comment: @КириллШрейдер, покажите строку кода с той ошибкой