# Как дозаписать информацию в CSV через Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Всем привет. Нужно дозаписывать информацию в CSV-файл через PD, но у меня при таком коде

```
def save(self, path): 
    fileWrite = open(*path*, 'a', encoding='UTF-8')
        data = pandas.DataFrame([
          [self.data['matchDate'], self.data['names']['home']
          [self.data['matchDate'], self.data['names']['away']
        ], columns=['Дата', 'Команды')
        data.to_csv(*fileWrite*, index=False, sep=';')
```

получается следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная функция вызывается в цикле для каждого элемента:

```
for item in matchList: 
      item.save(path)
```

Как убрать пробелы между строками, и заголовки оставить только на 1 строке?

Comment: По-нормальному нужно добавлять данные в датафрейм в памяти, а потом целиком файл перезаписывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему появляются пустые строки?

Смотрим документацию по методу [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv):

> DataFrame.**to_csv**(*path_or_buf=None*, *sep=','*, *na_rep=''*,
> *float_format=None*, *columns=None*, *header=True*, *index=True*, *index_label=None*, *mode='w'*, *encoding=None*, *compression='infer'*, *quoting=None*, *quotechar='"'*, *line_terminator=None*, *chunksize=None*, *date_format=None*, *doublequote=True*, *escapechar=None*, *decimal='.'*, *errors='strict'*, *storage_options=None*)[[source]](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L3376-L3568)[¶](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)
>
> Write object to a comma-separated values (csv) file.
>
> - Parameters
>
>   **path_or_buf** - str, path object, file-like object, or None, default NoneString, path object (implementing os.PathLike[str]), or
>   file-like object implementing a write() function. If None, the result
>   is returned as a string. If a non-binary file object is passed, it
>   should be opened with newline=’’, disabling universal newlines. If a
>   binary file object is passed, mode might need to contain a ‘b’.
>
> ...

Первое: `If a non-binary file object is passed, it should be opened with newline=’’, disabling universal newlines` - означает, что если первым параметром передан открытый текстовый файл, то он должен быть открыт с параметром `newline=''`, [аналогично как при работе со стандартным модулем csv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663990/1365).

Можно также не открывать файл вручную, а указать первым параметром имя файла, режим с дозаписью указать через параметр `mode` (см. кусок документации выше, по умолчанию он `mode='w'`, меняете на `mode='a'`).

Второе: видим волшебный параметр `header=True`, который, очевидно, отвечает за добавление заголовков. Соответственно вам нужно указать `header=False`.

---

Но, конечно же, лучше не дозаписывать по одной строке в файл в цикле, а сформировать датафрейм, потом сохранить его целиком.